# Windows Crashes & restarts itself but no message

Tags: crash

I have Dell workstation with following specs :

- CPU : Xeon E5645
- RAM : 12 GB
- GPUs ; Three AMD FirePro 2460 Low Profile Cards ( To run 12 Monitors )
- 12 Dell Monitors ( 1920x1200 )
- Windows - 7

I have been using this system for last 10 years with no problem. Reason for Win-7 is that System & Cards won't run Win-10.
Recently one Fan that sucks the air & throws inside the system was making noise but system never crashed.
I cleaned the system with a blower & took out dirt. Now it makes much less noise.

But it crashes 1 to 3 times a day & restarts itself & takes much longer 10 to 20 minutes to boot.
There is no message when restarting like graphics drivers crashed or dumping memory etc.

System is in an A/C room ( keeping temp at 86 degree F )

Can you please tell me:

1. What is causing windows to crash?
2. Why is it taking so long boot?
3. What should I do?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1.) **Software or Hardware issue**

a.) *Hardware*

- Power Supply: if a circuit fails that needs to establish the voltage persistency for motherboard that could cause crash. I recommend to have a spare one and change it.
- RAM: make a memtest. You can find the utility on any Linux boot disk. Boot from a disc or from an USB and let run the memtest.
- Motherboard: older capacitors on the motherboard used to being "humped". This is the sign of age. In this case motherboard need to be changed.

b.) *Software*

```
sfc /scannow
```

This scan checks the integrity of your OS. It works with [Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) too.

2.) **HDD issue**

a.) Slow boot can be because on old 5400rpm HDD. Change it to an SSD or a faster 7200 rpm HDD.

b.) Slow boot can be because a fragmented file structure. Run defrag command on your host.

```
defrag -h
```

c.) Slow boot can be because the HDD fails. Run chkdsk command on your host.

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

3.) **Buy new hardware parts do some maintenance activity**

a.) Being sure that the problem is hardware related. Take a new HDD and install a new OS on it. A freshly deployed OS should not have been crashing. If crashes you have HW related issue.

Unfortunately putting your existing OS to another computer is more difficult and wouldn't help anyhow. Don't waste your time to do that.

*Recommendation: I would take a new HDD anyway and would make a block based backup by using dd command and would start any repair activity only after it.*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time with many suggestions. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome. I hope it will help or at least you can use as some kind of reference. Good luck.